# Yii2 kartik datetime picker retain value after page submitting

Tags: php, yii2, bootstrap-datetimepicker, kartik-v

I am using [yii2-widget-datetimepicker](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker) in my `yii2` project. I want to retain the value of it after submitting the page.

```
<form action="index" method="post" >


<?=
                DateTimePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'datetime_10',
                    'options' => [
                            'placeholder' => 'Start Date Time',
                            'autocomplete' => 'off',
                        'required' =>true,
                            ],
                    'convertFormat' => false,
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:i:ss',
                        //'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'autoclose' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
                <?=
                DateTimePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'datetime_11',
                    'options' => [
                            'placeholder' => 'End Date Time',
                            'autocomplete' => 'off',
                            'required' =>true,
                            ],
                    'convertFormat' => false,
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:i:ss',
                        //'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'autoclose' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
</form>
```

How to retain the selected date-time value? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to set the `value` property of that widget?

Comment: @MichalHynčica, I have tried but not sure I did it correct way or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further tweaks, you could do

```php
<form action="index" method="post">
    <?=
    DateTimePicker::widget([
        'name'          => 'datetime_10',
        'value'         => Yii::$app->request->post('datetime_10', null),
        'options'       => [
            'placeholder'  => 'Start Date Time',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'required'     => true,
        ],
        'convertFormat' => false,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:i:ss',
            //'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'autoclose'      => true,
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
    <?=
    DateTimePicker::widget([
        'name'          => 'datetime_11',
        'value'         => Yii::$app->request->post('datetime_11', null),
        'options'       => [
            'placeholder'  => 'End Date Time',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'required'     => true,
        ],
        'convertFormat' => false,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format'         => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:i:ss',
            //'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'autoclose'      => true,
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
</form>
```

But this is not reliable. If you are gathering data throughout multiple pages, you should really consider storage/persistence, at least session & save to database after all the forms are completed, or skip session and go directly with in-memory data, a database etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should assigne a value realted  to  your nodel->field and assigne/reassigne the value you need  after (or before ) subimit

```
<?=
    DateTimePicker::widget([
        'name' => 'datetime_10',
        'value' => $yourModel->yourField, // <------ this 
        'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Start Date Time',
                'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'required' =>true,
                ],
        'convertFormat' => false,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:i:ss',
            //'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
            'todayHighlight' => true,
            'autoclose' => true,
        ]
    ]);
 ?>
```

Comment: I am selecting date-time from the user at run time

Comment: and the what do you mean with   retain the value of it after ...  if you want to show the inserted  value after the submit?  .. you want show the same date  in a second forms ??  then you should assign the value entered  the first time to a model and render ..